# How to check a JSON file with instanceof?

Tags: javascript, json, object, instanceof

I have this json file with a list of events.
I want to do a instance of that JSON file to check if there are any events that matches the Webinar classs and then to show it into the DOM but I get errors or nothing at all when I use an if or a forEach.

events.json

```
[{
      "title": "Easter",
      "date": "4.5.2021",
      "time": "23:00 PM",
      "LiveEvent": {
        "location": "Ireland",
        "adress": "Centrul Vechi 21"
      },
      "party": {"theme" : " '70s "}
    },
    {
      "title": "Party",
      "date": "14.11.2025",
      "time": "2:00 PM",
      "webinar": {
        "webinarTitle": "Com",
        "webinarLink": "https://google.com"
      },
      "party": {"theme" : " '70s "}
    },
    {
      "title": "Birthday",
      "date": "30.11.2021",
      "time": "7:00 PM",
      "webinar": {
        "webinarTitle": "Drinks",
        "webinarLink": "https://drinks.com"
      },
      "LiveEvent": {
        "location": "Cluj",
        "adress": "Centrul Vechi 21"
      }
    }
]
```

Webinar class

```
class Webinar extends Event {
  constructor(title, time, date, webinarTitle, webinarLink){
      super(title, date, time)
      this.webinarTitle = webinarTitle
      this.webinarLink = webinarLink
  }

  show() {
      console.log("This " + this.webinarTitle + " webinar " + "is hosted on " + this.webinarLink)
  }
}
```

Comment: _"I want to do a instance of that JSON file"_ please may you explain this a bit more? I assume you're parsing the JSON first?

Comment: yes, i am parsing the JSON with a XHR request and then i want to do a instanceof of the response to check if events has webinar property

Comment: What I don't understand (this might be my own issue) is what "do a instanceof" means? May you share how you expect it to work?

Comment: i want to check each object if it has webinar property like if(events instanceof Webinar) {...} but it doesn't work

Comment: Ah, then no. Parsed JSON doesn't become an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is a means of serializing suitable JavaScript values (restrictions apply) into text and reversing the process by parsing the text to recreate the serialized value. JSON **does not** serialize the class of an object.

Also JSON only serializes own properties - nothing in the prototype chain of an object is converted into text.

The short answer is trying to use `instanceOf` on parsed JSON object values is ineffective: any parsed object values are instances of Object and nothing else.

---

**Potential solution**

Part of the problem may be that the `class Webinar` code doesn't match the JSON posted. Try

```
class Webinar extends Event {
  constructor(title, time, date, webinarTitle, webinarLink){
      super(title, date, time)
      this.webinar = {webinarTitle, webinarLink};  // object property
  }

  show() {
      console.log("This " + this.webinar.webinarTitle + " webinar " + "is hosted on " + this.webinar.webinarLink)
  }
}
```

to extend `Event` and then after encoding and decoding JSON, check if it was originally a `Webinar` object by checking if it has a `webinar` property:

```
if( event.webinar) {
   // yes it WAS a Webinar object...
}
```

As a final aside, JSON doesn't serialize function objects: the decoded `Webinar` object will be an ordinary object with methods inherited from `Object.prototype`. No original methods such as `show` will be present on decoded objects.